# Problems with dimensions in Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

**Question**
Let $V,W$ be subspace of a Hilbert space. If $\dim V<\infty$ and $\dim V<\dim W$, show that there is a $u\in W$ such that $\|u\|=1$ and $(u,v)=0$ for all $v\in V$．

I solved this problem in the following way：

*proof*

If $\dim V=n$, it can be expressed as $V=\langle v_1,\dots,v_n\rangle$. Using the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization method, we can turn this basis into an orthogonal basis $V=\langle e_1,\cdots,e_n\rangle$. From $\dim V<\dim W$, there exists $w \in W$ such that $\{e_1,\cdots,e_n,w\}$ is linearly independent. Here, we set
\begin{align}
e_{n+1}'=w-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(w,e_i)}{(e_i,e_i)}e_i
\end{align}
Then, $e_{n+1}'$ is orthogonal to each $e_k\ (k=1,2,\dots,n)$．
Therefore, if we set $\displaystyle{u=\frac{e_{n+1}'}{\|e_{n+1}'\|}}$, then $\|u\|=1$, and any $v\in V$ can be expressed as $v=a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n$, so we have $(u,v)=0$．
${\Box}$

However, we noticed that this proof does not say that u is an element of W.
Can we modify the proof so that u is an element of W?

Comment: Maybe there was an additional assumption that $V \subset W$?

Answer (score 0):

Pick $n+1$ L.I. vectors in $W$ and $W_1$ be their span. If we prove the result with $W$ repalced by $W_1$ we are done. Now we can replace the entire Hilbert space $H$ by $V+W$, so we can work in a finite dimansional Hilbert space. Let $N$ be its dimension. Then $dim (V)+dim V^{\perp}=N$ where $V^{\perp}=(\{x\in H: (x,v)=0 \forall v \in V\})$. Note that $dim (V) <dim(W)$ now impies that there exists $u_1 \in W \cap V^{\perp}, u_1 \neq 0$. [$W \cap V^{\perp} =\{0\}$ would imply $dim (W)+dim (V^{\perp}) \leq N$ which then would make $dim (V)+dim (V^{\perp}) < N$].  Take $u=\frac {u_1} {\|u_1\|}$.

Comment: I couldn't figure out that $W\cap V^{\perp}$ was not empty.
Specifically, I don't understand why $\dim V+\dim V^{\perp} \leq N$ and then $\dim V+\dim V^{\perp}<N$ when $W \cap V^{\perp}$ is assumed to be empty.

Comment: There was a typo. I have corrceted it. [ Take  a basis for $W$ and  a basis for $V^{\perp}$. The union of these two is linearly independent  if  $W \cap V^{\perp} =\{0\}$. The number of elements in this union cannot exceed the total dimension $N$ of our Hlibert space. So $dim(W)+dim(V^{\perp}) \leq N$].  @epsilon